# XPages, close window from dialog box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, xpages

I have a dialog box / bootstrap modal which opens on page load. The user has to click a checkbox confirming they have read and understood some text, which then makes the continue button which is disabled, clickable.

However, I also have a close/cancel button, which when clicked, closes the dialog button, and at present, simply makes all fields on the form disabled.

What I want to do, is if they click cancel, that it closes the dialog box, AND the browser window.... I've tried adding `window.close()` to the onComplete event of the button but get

> Script interpreter error, line=1, col=8: [ReferenceError] 'window' not
>   found

Would I be right in assuming this is because the dialog is presented on page load, so it doesn't have a "handle" on the window?

I'm thinking of putting a hidden button on the form which does a `window.close()` and telling my onComplete code from the dialog button to click it to achieve what I want, but just wondered if a) that will even work (I can obviously test it myself tomorrow morning) but b) and more importantly, is this the best/right way to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Users use many kinds of browsers and there is a chance, your intent/code simply won't work.

My 2 cents: instead of closing window, empty the content of the window with explanation why it happened. Something very similar to Domino logoff page (please close all browser windows/tabs tada tada).